# Spinning PDF's by passing a URL and $_GET parameters?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have spent a lot of time trying to get dompdf (http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) to work but I keep running into problems.  I am trying to generate a PDF from a PHP script which generates a fairly complex, filled out web form.  The script accepts a $_GET parameter (record number) and fills out the form accordingly with data from the database.  I have no problem getting this data into the script as a string or any type of value really. What I am wondering is what the best approach would be for converting this type of data to a PDF?

The flow is as follows: user completes form and is taken to confirmation page which I would like to add a "Save as PDF" button.  At this point one of two things could happen, the page that is currently being displayed in the browser could be spun directly to a pdf or a call to itself (scriptname.php?id=xyz) could be made using something like PHP's http_get() function and store the HTML as a string.  From there I am having issues with preparing an accurate representation as a PDF.

I have heard some talk about fpdf but their examples don't really lead me to believe you can use dynamic data as the source, but please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Any input would be appreciated.

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't know dompdf. Strange that it uses either a commercial library (PDFlib) or an outdated (?) one (CPDF, not updated for 3 years). But well, as long as it works (concept is interesting).

I don't understand what you mean by "use dynamic data as the source" (or rather, I see not point in generating static PDF!), but FPDF is used to generate various dynamic documents, like invoices in e-commerce products. I saw people using forks (like [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)) to handle Unicode data, though.

You can't transform an HTML page to PDF with FPDF, but you have a quite precise control of layout, using concept of cells with data.
You can see such kind of code there: http://svn.prestashop.com/trunk/classes/PDF.php

Answer (score 0):

In the past when faced with this issue, I have used FPDF for the placement of data on a PDF template.  Then, by setting the appropriate HTTP header, force the browser to pop open the Download / Save As box for the user to save said PDF.

In a class that extends FPDF/FPDI appropriately, use something like the following to generate a PDF from a template PDF you've already created (http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/):

```
$this->setSourceFile('pdf_template.pdf');
$template_page = $this->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
$this->useTemplate($template_page, 0, 0);
```

Then, have FPDF generate the PDF for output using:

```
$this->Output();
```

You can also extend FPDF to accept (limited) HTML for formatting using the script found here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php